# How do I get all candidate in a position

Tags: python, html, django

Am trying to query every candidate that belong to a specific position and loop through it using the django template in my html. If I have just one position/poll all candidate will display in my frontend, but once i add another position/poll then the list of the candidate will not display again

```
def index(request):
    context = {}
    instruction = ""
    positions = Position.objects.order_by('priority').all()
    for position in positions:
        candidates = Candidate.objects.filter(position=position)
        for candidate in candidates:
            votes = Votes.objects.filter(candidate=candidate).count()
            if position.max_vote > 1:
                instruction = "You may select up to " + str(position.max_vote) + " candidates"
            else:
                instruction = "Select only one candidate"


    context = {
        'positions': positions,
        'candidates': candidates,
        'votes': votes,
        'instruction': instruction
    }
    return render(request, 'poll/index.html', context)
```

```
{% block content %}

<div class="row">
  <div class="mt-5">
    {% for p in positions %}
    {{ instruction }}
      <h1>{{ p.name }}</h1>
      <p>{{ p.description }}</p>
      {% for c in candidates %}
        <h1>{{ candidate.fullname }}</h1>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
  
</div>
  

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as much I understand you are querying objects inside the for loop and you are not storing the result of each iteration, whenever the next iterations happen, that overwrite the candidates and votes variable...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please can you show a little working code that i could follow